# How to setup react environment in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs

I learn reactjs separately but now I am integrating ReactJS with asp.net, I tried a lot but still I am not able to work on react with asp.net.
How I use reactjs as I am using in vs code by just making a java script file and writing all the jsx in it.

I am following the tutoril https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnet4.html I follow the same steps but I am stuck on JavaScriptEngineSwitcher in my ReactConfig.cs file code mentioned here which give error.

These lines of ReactConfig.cs gives error

```
 line no.3 using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8;
    lineno.12.JsEngineSwitcher.Current.DefaultEngineName=
V8JsEngine.EngineName;
    line no.13.JsEngineSwitcher.Current.EngineFactories.AddV8();
```

My ReactConfig.cs file snapshot mentioned here

Comment: do you want to perform server side rendering in asp.net using react? else there is no need to use reactjs.net. React JS is a javascript library that doest need any server side components

Comment: Sujit.Warrier, I am just want to use reactjs for front end in asp.net so please can you tell me what steps I do to integrate reactjs with asp.net.

Comment: if you use bundling then all you need to do is  add the bundle to the  view or aspx page using a script tag aling the the react CDNs

Comment: this is a good enough example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/my-first-react-application-with-asp-net-mvc/. though the bundling here is done by the .net framework, its always better to use webpack to do this then manually add the bundle yourself

Comment: I follow this tutorial which you suggest but it does not work for me one thing which is not clear for me is that @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main") how I add this? it gives error : 'Script' does not exist in the current context